# Open specific ports in CoovaChilli

Tags: hotspot, freeradius

I have set up an hotspot with CoovaChilli and freeRADIUS. Everything is working fine. I get a landing page, after logging in, I am able to access internet.

Now, I have also hosted a web server which is listening at port 3740 in the same system as CoovaChilli and freeRADIUS. I am not able to access that port from any system connected to the hotspot.

My wifi hotspot access point IP is 192.168.10.1 and the webserver is running at port 3740. Even if I login to my hotspot, the port is not accessible. Can you let me know how to open this port?

command

> *$ netstat -an | grep :3740*

output

> *tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:3740       :::*                    LISTEN*

Comment: Is the hotspot in the same network as the webserver? if not, have you the routes setup correctly (as it will probably try to find your webserver by diverting the traffic through the default gateway). Can you access your webserver from another computer in the same network - check you firewall settings on the webserver and from which interfaces it will allow connections)

Comment: I have set up the hotspot and the webserver in the same network. None of the computers connected in the same network are able to access the webserver. Internally only the webserver is accessible.

Comment: So the webserver is in the 192.168.10.x/24 (I assume) network. Can you explain what you mean by "Internally only the webserver is accessible"? Can you access the webserver from any network or only from the webserver itself? After rereading your post/comments it looks like a firewall on the webserver issue or the webserver is not listening on all interfaces. Could you edit your Q with the output of `netstat -an | grep :3740` or `netstat -an | findstr :3740` depending if your webserver is on linux/windows.

Comment: By Internally, I meant, in the local browser or by the command "wget 192.168.10.1:3740". The output of the command netstat gives me the following: **$ netstat -an | grep :3740** ouput: **tcp6       0      0 192.168.10.1:3740       :::*                    LISTEN **

Comment: Please update your Q with the netstat output and firewall settings.

Comment: Yes I have done it now

Comment: And there is your problem, it listens only for request from the webserver itself. You have to set it to listen on all interfaces. Check your webserver set up.

Comment: I have now updated the server to listen in all interfaces. In the same server I did **wget http://192.168.10.1:3740** to test **wlan0** and **wget http:\\192.168.1.2:3740** to test the **eth0**

Comment: I am able to access the webserver through all the computers connected in eth0 but the ports are blocked in wlan0. Can it be because coovachilli hotspot in wlan0 is blocking it?

Comment: First check your firewall settings on the webserver. Can you ping from another computer from the wlan network? check with `arp -a` even if the ping does not reply if you get the arp list populated with the webserver wlan MAC.

Comment: I am able to ping the webserver's computer(192.168.10.1) from another computer(192.168.10.3) which is connected through wlan0. I am not able to access the port 3740, only 3990 and 4990 are accessible since they are coovachilli ports.

Comment: You now have the webserver listen on all interfaces on port 3740 and you should open the port in the firewall (as you said you are able to connect on those other ports).

Comment: Can you tell me how do i do that. i have tried iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 3740 ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 3740 ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 3740 -j ACCEPT

Comment: I think a `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 3740 -j ACCEPT` should suffice.

Comment: Hi Zina, thanks for the help. I had to change the coovachilli config file to allow the ports
>HS_TCP_PORTS="3740"

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution:
I had to change the coovachilli config file to allow the ports

> HS_TCP_PORTS="3740"